# How do I go back within webview after navigation to a different fragment from the webview fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-navigation

I have been trying to figure out a way to go back within `WebView` after leaving the `WebView fragment`. The dilemma is as follows:

1. I load the `WebView fragment` `page1.html`
2. Then I navigate within it such that `page1.html?navigate=page2.html`.
3. Then I navigate to a different `Fragment` on click of some event in the `WebView fragment`, say I click a symbol that brings in `"NotAwebviewfragment.java"`
4. Then I click back from `notawebviewfragment` then it takes me to the `WebView page` I left from. However when I click back again it take me to the previous `Fragment` that was open before `WebView`.
5. Now If I stay within the `WebViewFragment` I can navigate back and
   forth as desired. However, once I leave it, it gives me access to
   the `WebView` only once.

Here's the code so far:
    Within the webview:

```
public boolean webViewSteppedBack() {       
        if (webview != null && webview.canGoBack()) {   
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

public boolean backPressed(final MainActivity mainActivity) {
    if (webViewSteppedBack()) {
         if(!EikonUtils.isTablet(getActivity())) {
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
          }
            return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

`MainActivity` (which contains the fragment navigation code for back):

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();

         if (backPressListener != null) {
             boolean b = false;  
             //Making sure we trigger the backPressed event if the listener is the top fragment
             String bplTag = ((Fragment) backPressListener).getTag(); 
             String topFragemtnTag = "";  
             if (topFragment != null) { 
                 topFragemtnTag = topFragment.getTag(); 
                 if (bplTag != null && topFragemtnTag != null && bplTag.equals(topFragemtnTag)) {    
                      b = backPressListener.backPressed(this); 

                 }  

             }
             if (b) { return;  }          
             if (!NotAWebViewFragment.TAG_NOT.equals(bplTag)) { 
                 backPressListener = null; 
             }   
        }

    }
```

Comment: @CommonsWare any input on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method in your fragment in which you are defining the webView.

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                            mWebView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: it gives me an error" method does not override from its superclass"

Comment: That doesn't seem to take me back to the previous layer of webview, behavior stays the same. My issue is,even if it goes back and forth as expected within the webview, as soon as you skip the fragment containing the webview by clicking on a link within the webview which calls another fragment, its difficult to navigate back to the previous layers of webview. Say fragment A contains the webview with google.com, then you click on a link google.com/somethingnew.html then within it you click on something say "click here to call a native fragment" , it goes to the fragment, then u click back and ..

Comment: it shows the previous fragment as expected with google.com/somethingnew.html but when u click back again it goes to the previous fragment before the fragment containing the webview, whereas it should be able to navigate within the same fragment loading "google.com" when back button is pressed. Now one interesting thing is, if i stay within the fragment containing webview, I can navigate back and forth as many layers as I want as long as I dont skip out of it to another fragment.

Comment: Can you put a debugger inside the onKey method and check whether control is going inside this or not when you pressed a back button from another fragment.

Comment: I am thinking , it won't go inside the onKey method when you back pressed because when you click back from another fragment web view lost the request and the fragment(containing web view ) get the focus. So if this was  the case then you need to implement  onBackPressed inside the fragment.

Comment: I do have a onbackpressed in mainactivity, which is the one handling fragment to fragment backpresses. is there a way I can manipulate that to recognize the previous webview and /or send control to that fragment to allow navigation within webview layers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115747/discussion-between-aman-jain-and-justice-bauer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add all  the fragment to the [back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). In activity's onBackPressed method, you can get the current active fragment. You can check if the active fragment is the instance of Awebviewfragment and if the webview can navigate back otherwise pop the current active fragment from the stack using [popBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html)() method of fragment manager.
Here are the code snippet:
1. to add fragment

private void addNotAwebviewfragment() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        notAwebviewfragment = NotAwebviewfragment.newInstance("test", "test");

```
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contents, notAwebviewfragment, NotAwebviewfragment.TAG_NOT).addToBackStack(NotAwebviewfragment.TAG_NOT);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void addFragWebview(){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    webViewFragment = Awebviewfragment.newInstance("test", "test");
    webViewFragment.setFragmentListener(weblistener);
    backPressListener = webViewFragment;
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contents, webViewFragment, Awebviewfragment.TAG).addToBackStack(Awebviewfragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

2. In onBackPRessed() in main activity:
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

   ```
   Fragment fragment = getActiveFragment();

   if(fragment instanceof Awebviewfragment){
       System.out.println("web view fragment");
       if(backPressListener != null && backPressListener.backPressed(this)){
           System.out.println("web view fragment will return");
           return;
       }
   }

   int count = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
   if (count > 0 ){
       supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
   }else {
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

   }
3. get active fragment:
   public Fragment getActiveFragment() {
       if (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
           return null;
       }
       String tag = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
       return supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
   }

you can check with the sample committed in the [github](https://github.com/Praveen935/WebViewNavigationWithFragment.git/).